# Find the pdf of piecewise random variable involving identity functions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$X$ is a standard normal random variable.

$Y = g(X)$, where $g(x)=-I_{(-\infty,0)}(x) + \frac12I_{\{0\}}(x)+I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$.

I'm trying to find the pdf for $Y$. I know to start with $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)$, but I don't know where to go from here with the piecewise function, especially when it's just the identity function.

Comment: $Y$ has no PDF since it is a discrete random variable (as was shown by V.V). It has a PMF.

Answer (score 0):

As $X$ is continuous r.v., then the probability of getting $x=0$ is $0$, thus $Y$ can only receive two values; either $-1$ or $1$, hence
$$
P_Y(y) = P(Y=y)=\frac{1}{2}, \quad y\in\{-1,1\}.
$$ 
While $1/2$ stems from the fact that $P(X\le 0) = \Phi(0)=1/2$.

Comment: Thanks! What does the phi stand for here?

Comment: It is the cdf of standard normal random variable